# How can I pass data loaded when my application finished launching thru my UITabBar to a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xcode10

I am a new iOS programmer and I am trying to make an application that involves the following flow:

```
-> UITabBar -> UINavController -> UITableViewController.
```

Initially the program was working when I have the following flow:

```
-> UINavController -> UITableViewController
```

But when I added the UITabBar (with the Embed In method)the I had two issues:

1) Casting the initial view from UITableView to UITabBarView
2) The data which have been restored from Archives of the phone are not loading in the TableView.

I managed to fix the casting issue with the UIStoryboard IDs, but I am not sure if this way I created the second problem of not passing data to the UITableView correctly.

The Casting problem has taking place at the appDelegate code. Here is the original code I had before incorporating the UITabBarView:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

let navController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

let SLBprojectController = navController.topViewController as! GR8TableView

SLBprojectController.SLBprojectDB = thisSLBprojectDB

return true
}
```

The problem with the above code was that it told me that it could not cast a TableViewController (GR8TableView) into a UITabBarView. I have managed to fix this by searching in the StackOverflow forums by making the following:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let tabBarIntial : UITabBarController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBar") as! UITabBarController

let navigationController:UINavigationController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navController") as! UINavigationController

let navigationController1:UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController1")

let SLBprojectController = navigationController.topViewController as! GR8TableView

SLBprojectController.SLBprojectDB = thisSLBprojectDB

tabBarIntial.viewControllers = [navigationController, navigationController1]

tabBarIntial.selectedIndex = 0

return true

}
```

But after I fixed the "casting" issue then I am getting problems loading the data in the TableView. Not sure if this problem is related to the way I fixed the casting issue.

Any assistance would be much much appreciated!

Comment: You're building a controller hierarchy in code but I suspect it's a duplicate of what is being done automatically by loading the storyboard.  My main reason for thinking this way is that you don't do anything with `tabBarIntial` such as making it your root controller.  (Also, you don't say that your tab bar controller isn't appearing.)  So, specifically, I'll guess that the controller you're giving the DB to isn't the same instance you see.

Comment: With a more complex flow like what you have here, can I recommend you research the [App Coordinator](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/71/how-to-use-the-coordinator-pattern-in-ios-apps) pattern? I wish i had learned it when I was new. I have linked you to an example of this pattern using Storyboards since I imagine it would be difficult at this stage to comprehend UI without storyboards, but there are other examples where people use xibs.

Comment: @PhillipMills thank you for the clarification. I attach the DB to one of the viewControllers of the tabBarIntial. What else would I do? Any code to try would be much appreciated!

Comment: @Miladinho thanks for the App Coordinator link. I will check it out and revert with any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer would be to go back to logic similar to what worked for you, but with a slightly more complex relationship.  For example, I created an app with a tab bar controller, a navigation controller in the first tab, and a `FirstViewController` embedded in the navigation controller.

Since I don't have a database, I gave the `FirstViewController` a single instance variable called `running`.

The following code finds the controller and sets the variable:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let tabController = window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        if let navController = tabController.viewControllers![0] as? UINavigationController {
            if let firstController = navController.topViewController as? FirstViewController {
                firstController.running = true
            } else {
                print("Unexpected controller in navigation hierarchy: \(String(describing: navController.topViewController))")
            }
        } else {
            print("Unexpected contained controller: \(String(describing: tabController.viewControllers![0]))")
        }
    } else {
        print("Unexpected root controller: \(String(describing: window!.rootViewController))")
    }
    return true
}
```

Note that I'm not creating any new controllers.  That's all done by default storyboard loading.

I believe you should be able to adapt this to your own variable and class names.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code - let me have a look and revert. I agree with your principle that the solution is close to what used to work for me in the beginning. I will review tomorrow - as it is getting very late - and come back. thanks Again!

Comment: Too curious to wait for tomorrow! I have reviewed the code and at this moment I am getting the following error in the TableViewController which is linked to the topViewController of the navigation controller: "Property 'self.SLBprojectDB' not initialized at super.init call". I get this error message to the init() of the TableView:  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){super.init(coder: aDecoder) ; navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem}

Comment: Since that property is provided after the controller is created, you probably need to make it an optional.  If you guarantee that it will be provided before you use it, you can force unwrap it the same as outlets are treated.